# Verbose output in logfile and simple output on screen?

Tags: shell-script, pipe, output, csh, tee

Let's say I have the following script: script.sh and i want the verbose output in a logfile and simple output on screen.

Logfile should contain the `csh -v script.sh` output, and on the screen should be only the script.sh output.

I prefer using piped tee.

Comment: It works for `ksh` as the debug messages are redirected to STDERR, but it doesn't work for `csh`

Comment: 2>filename
      # Redirect stderr to file "filename." Are you sure?

Comment: Yes , I am damn sure it does.

Comment: I reversed my vote here because I'm not sure I know what's going on. I think I'd rather see a copy of your script.

Comment: [This](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) definitely confirms @g4ur4v's assertion. And makes me glad I never had to use the `cshell`. Please accept my apology - apparently I did not... *the google*...